# Arrays, function calls, and object files in C

Tags: arrays, c, stack

I have some questions regarding how the size of arrays changes the size of the binary in C program.

Suppose I have a program like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f()
{
    int array[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        array[i] = i;
}

int main(void)
{
    float m[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        m[i] = 2 * i;

    f();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a silly example, but I think it can help to illustrate my questions:
Do the arrays (*m* and *array*) affect the size of the binary? If so, how?
If I never call the function *f()*, will *array* still exists on the binary, thus affecting its size?
If *f()* is on an external (static) library, how the final binary size change?

I've tried to experiment using the *size* command, and no matter the size of the arrays, the binary is always the same size.

I hope my questions are clearly enough. Thanks. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the arrays (m and array) affect the size of the binary? If so, how?

No, these arrays are allocated on the stack, so it will only affect the stack, not the size on the disk

> If I never call the function f(), will array still exists on the binary, thus affecting its size?

It's the same answer like above.

> If f() is on an external (static) library, how the final binary size change?

It will change differ from some bytes (Size of the entry for dynamical linking vs the size of the machinecode of the function)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I was a little confused about the heap and the stack.